# Adding option values to a select box by comma spaced values

Tags: javascript

How can the code below be modified, such that I would be able to add single and comma separated values to a select box?

Example 1: orange

[SELECT BOX]

```
orange
```

Example2: red,blue,green,yellow

[SELECT BOX]

```
red
blue
green
yellow
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add() {

var select = document.getElementById('list') 

var option = document.getElementById('reference').value

select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(option, option)

}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="add()">
<input type="text" id="reference">
<br><br>
<select style="width: 200px;" id="list"><option>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply split the value by a comma, and then loop through each of the strings, appending the option as you go:

```
function add() {
    var select = document.getElementById('list')
    var options = document.getElementById('reference').value.split(',');
    for(i=0; i<options.length; i++){
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(options[i], options[i])
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7YD/1/)